# How to know work item type from work item id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

i have work item id

```
int id =int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"],System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
WorkItem item= DataManager.DevelopmentProject.Store.GetWorkItem(id);
```

i need to know what [image: var type = item.GetType() in type fields]is the work item type ?(bug,change request etc.)

Answer (score 2):

i solved this like this

```
item.Fields["Work Item Type"].Value
```

Answer (score -2):

I would use :

```
var type = item.GetType()
if(type == typeof(Bug))
{
    //Do something
}
...
```

Comment: its not working  i can not get work item type with GetType()

Comment: Ok so please give us more details. GetType() get the type of the object. Is there inheritance ?

Comment: when i run var type = item.GetType()
 in  type has many fields but not about type.

Comment: that is exactly what I did... I commented on my post because i had not sufficient reputation. I understand I tried to answer a question without enough information, based on what I understood. I couldn't ask him a question so I provided an answer... I'm trying to help here, maybe i should not...